# jpa query not returning results by applying OR clause

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a use case to search all the cities for a given stateId and if name is present then include that in the query and if description is present then include as part of the query. stateID is mandatory but if name or description is not passed the query will not filter out the result. I have written the `jpql` as below but I need an `OR` condition between name and description. currently the result is and AND of name and description but

- I need name OR description.
- Also the description should not match the exact string passed but should be `LIKE` matching string

  ```
  @Query("select c from City c where (c.stateID=:stateId and ((:name is null or c.name=:name) and  (:description is null or c.description=:description)))")
  ```

where am I doing wrong in the above query which I wrote.

Comment: perhaps if you look at the SQL generated by your chosen JPA provider ? in its log

Comment: Hibernate is smart enough to handle and and or conditions so just post mysql log generated by JPA ....